# I want to PROGRAMMATICALLY change the roles that can view a block

Tags: users, blocks

What I really want is that I have a block and I want it to be shown only for authenticated users.

Can anyone help me?

**Note**: I want to do it programmatically without an extra module.

Comment: admin is also authenticated, is that what you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69861/how-to-assign-block-access-programmatically (assigning access to the "authenticated user" role in your case). BTW, it would be useful to edit the original question to mention that you want to do it programmatically ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[hook_block_list_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_list_alter/7)

`global $user;`

check `$user->roles` and `unset` your block:

```
function modulename_block_list_alter(&$blocks){
  global $user;
  $roles = $user->roles;
  if(!in_array('authenticated user', $roles)){
    unset($blocks[6]); 
  }
  // 6 is actually a block id witch is 
  //an array key from $blocks
}
```

I have just tested it with simpletest and it works. You need to check the user roles also.

Comment: could you help me how to unset a block?

Comment: global $user;
  if (!isset($user->uid)) {
    unset($blocks[19]);
  }  this does not work for me

Comment: $user->id is allway set. like $user->id = 0 for anonymous

Comment: global $user;
  if ($user->uid = 0) {
    unset($blocks[19]);
  }     It also does not work again...

Comment: with $user->uid = 0 you just assignet 0 to $user->uid. Replace it with $user->uid == 0 or even better take a look on my last edit;)

Comment: again not working :/ :/ :/

Comment: copy-paste my code. change `modulename`, `6`, and `authenticated user` accordingly. I have tested it in simpletest

Comment: it works thx!!.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this module [block access](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_access)

Answer (score 2):

there is the option of assigning a role in the block settings under the `Visibility settings`.

Comment: use php code for the body section and put the condition `if($user == admin) { // body content }` the body content only show if user admin.

Comment: as body content what do you mean?

Comment: if you add block then you write your code under "Block body".

Comment: Is the main-menu block from admin_menu module

Comment: can you explain what actually you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you looking it through grammatically so follow this.

```
function hook_block_view($delta = '') {
  global $user;
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'demo_block1':
      if (in_array('Admin', array_values($user->roles))) {
        $block['content'] = t('Hello Admin');
      }
      break;

    case 'demo_block2':
      if ($user->uid) {
        $block['content'] = t('Hello Authenticated User');
      }
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}
```